# Issue with getting reading dictionary connected to object

Tags: python, class, object, methods, keyerror

I'm working on project and got a problem. When I tried to get the element of dictionary I got key error. Although when I doesn't use variable numer the program works. Even when variable = 2 The program doesn't work. Code:

```
from typing import Sequence
class Lot:
    def __init__(self, numer_lotu, id_samolotu,
                 czas_lotu, trasa, bramka,
                 cenaek, cenabiz, cenapr,
                 nrwolek = None, nrwolbiz= None, nrwolpr = None):
        self.numer_lotu = numer_lotu
        self.id_samolotu = id_samolotu
        self.czas_lotu = czas_lotu
        self.trasa = trasa
        self.bramka = bramka
        self.cenaek = cenaek
        self.cenabiz = cenabiz
        self.cenapr = cenapr
        self.nrwolek = nrwolek
        self.nrwolbiz = nrwolbiz
        self.nrwolpr = nrwolpr
    def get_numer_lotu(self):
        return self.numer_lotu
    def get_id_samolotu(self):
        return self.id_samolotu
    def get_czas_lotu(self):
        return self.czas_lotu
    def get_trasa(self):
        return self.trasa

    def get_bramka(self):
        return self.bramka
    def get_cenaek(self):
        return self.cenaek
    def get_cenabiz(self):
        return self.cenabiz
    def get_cenapr(self):
        return self.cenapr
    def get_wolnemiejscaek(self):
        return self.nrwolek
    def get_wolnemiejscabiz(self):
        return self.nrwolbiz
    def get_wolnemiejscapr(self):
        return self.nrwolpr
class DatabaseofLoty():
    def __init__(self, list_of_samolot : Sequence[Lot] = ()):
        self.list_of_samoloty = {lot.get_numer_lotu() : lot
                                for lot in list_of_samolot}
        print(self.list_of_samoloty)
        self.list_of_samolot = list_of_samolot
    def get_list(self):
        return self.list_of_samolot
    def get_dictionary(self):
        return self.list_of_samoloty
    def get_loty_by_numer_lotu(self, numer):
        print(self.list_of_samoloty[2])
        print(numer)
        return self.list_of_samoloty[numer]
```

When I tried to run this I got this as an output:

```
{1: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443f9ec70>}
{1: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443f9ec70>, 2: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443f9edc0>}
{1: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443fa2c10>}
{1: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443fa2c10>, 2: <lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443f42670>}
<lociki.Lot object at 0x7f4443f42670>
2
KeyError: '2'
```

Comment: Running that code produces no output

Comment: why do you have this line `self.list_of_samolot = list_of_samolot` ?

Comment: Line will be used for the next methods.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Please read [mre] and provide one. You need to show us a **minimal** (not a code dump) **example** of how those classes are being used when the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

2 (int), which is your key is not the same as '2' (str), which is what `numer` contains